# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, owin, assembly-binding-redirect

My ASP.Net MVC Application works fine when run locally on IIS, but gives the following error when deployed to Azure:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

This is the piece of the stack trace that led me to believe that SignalR is a potential culprit:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Owin.OwinExtensions.MapSignalR(IAppBuilder builder, String path, HubConfiguration configuration) +0
   Owin.OwinExtensions.MapSignalR(IAppBuilder builder, HubConfiguration configuration) +12
   QuikWorx.O365Web.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +169
```

According to NuGet, I have version 3.0.1 of Microsoft.Owin installed on the application, but apparently something (SignalR) requires version 2.1.0. I would have thought that the following bindingRedirect would force SignalR to use the installed version 3.0.1 (verified present, version 3.0.1 in /bin on Azure):

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

...but alas, this is not the case.

I've also tried the following without success:

- Forced reinstall of Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1 with NuGet.
- Forced reinstall of the SignalR component (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core) that requires Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0 with NuGet
- Changing the oldVersion of the bindingRedirect for Microsoft.Owin to "0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" (this makes no sense)
- Removing the bindingRedirect for Microsoft.Owin
- Deleting *all* files and folders in the site directory using `rd /Q /S` in Kudu

Is there anything else that I could attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Would love to get to the root cause of the issue, as in why it works locally, but not in Azure, but based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047887/27483) you should probably try to install Microsoft OWIN itself - via NuGet, directly to the project that's failing.

Comment: The Owin 1.0.0 package itself is already installed on the project.

Comment: @RyanShripat check the other projects (if any) and make sure they are all referencing the same versions. I would suggest checking package manger and see if there are any updates as well.